# GCD obtaining queue name/label

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, queue, grand-central-dispatch

How can I get the current queue name?

I mean queue label like `com.example.myqueue`.

In the Xcode 4 debugger I can see just `_block_invoke_1`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about [`dispatch_queue_get_label`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_queue_get_label.3.html)?

Answer (score 8):

In Objective-C you can log the label of the current queue with:

```
NSLog(@"%s", dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL));
```

In Swift (2.0):

```
print(String(UTF8String: dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL))!)
```