# Swift compare memory addresses

Tags: swift

I want to compare the addresses of two Swift objects, like:

```
let a: AnyObject
let b: AnyObject

a < b
```

Of course this is not possible like this but I’m not able to find any way to achieve this.

I could just implement a C function to do this

```
bool compare(NSObject *a, NSObject *b){
    return a < b;
}
```

and then call it like

```
compare(a, b)
```

but this limits me to use `NSObjects`.

So my question is: Is there any way to achieve this purely in Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [unsafeAddressOf](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs15unsafeAddressOfFPSs9AnyObject_GVSs13UnsafePointerT__) function that returns an `UnsafePointer` value.

```
let elm0 = "hello world"
let elm1 = UIButton()

let address0 = unsafeAddressOf(elm0)
let address1 = unsafeAddressOf(elm1)

let compare = address0 > address1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, much better than my own solution. Where is this documented? I was not able to find any function like this.

Comment: Yes, but how did you find that function? I don’t want to ask a question every time I'm looking for such a global function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058906/printing-a-variable-memory-address-in-swift

Comment: Ok, deep searching on Stack Overflow. Sadly Swift lacks documentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added a link to Apple documentation (prerelease, the link will have to be updated later).

Comment: @LucaAngeletti the documentation link does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I found myself an answer.

There is a struct called [`ObjectIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ObjectIdentifier_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015940-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) which can provide you a UIntValue to identify an object.

This UIntValue looks pretty much like it was the object reference, so I’ll use that:

```
class Person {
    var name: String

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

NSLog("%p", ObjectIdentifier(Person(name: "James")).uintValue)
NSLog("%p", ObjectIdentifier(Person(name: "Berta")).uintValue)
NSLog("%p", ObjectIdentifier(Person(name: "Charly")).uintValue)
```

Logs something similar to:

```
2015-08-29 15:04:21.567 App[10724:5283560] 0x7ff3a8415830
2015-08-29 15:04:21.568 App[10724:5283560] 0x7ff3a8643ba0
2015-08-29 15:04:21.568 App[10724:5283560] 0x7ff3a8415830
```