# Address of Array with LLDB

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

How to print the address of array in memory in lldb ?
I have tried to use command "e" with my array name but it gives me the content of the array and address of every element inside it.
i'm using xcode9.2.

if  i make a breakpoint on the array

[image: Wholedata is an array of BaseModel]

the array on the LLDB looks like this

[image: when press on the quick look]

and it doesn't give me the address.

and when type command "e" it looks like this

[image]

Comment: In your second image: what's the difference between the highlighted array and that first array in the variable list that does show a memory address?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've breakpointed on your array, if you look in the Variables View (the pane left of the lldb Console) it shows the variable's memory address.

[image: Array in Variables pane with memory address]

Edit: Above was actually before it was initialized. When I use the "e" command it seems to work:

```
(lldb) e defKeys
(__NSArrayI *) $1 = 0x000000011bd18220 @"35 elements"
```

You should also be able to hover over the array name in the Editor, click the inspector eyeball to show its memory address.

[image: Inspector popover]

Comment: please check the updated question , i have tried all these solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: @BathantHegazy hmmm, can you at least get the memory address using this method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741007/3731511