# Is it secure to use a hash of a memory location as identifier?

Tags: swift, security, hash

I generate a hash for some objects of classes based on their memory location (in this case for a websocket object from vapor swift).

<s>Unmanaged.passUnretained(webSocket).toOpaque().hashValue</s>

or:

```
ObjectIdentifier(webSocket).hashValue
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41666807/10551293 (The answer on how to get the memory location of an object)

I thought I'd use this as an Identifier (endusers could view this). Does this open a possibility for an attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift provides a tool specifically for this purpose: [`ObjectIdentifier()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objectidentifier#).

Its hash includes a per-launch random seed, specifically to frustrate hash-based attacks. Even if the attacker were to brute-force the hash (itself a significant, but possibly not impossible problem), it will not reveal the actual location in memory. This should be a secure identifier.

But be sure to use `ObjectIdentifier`. If an attack were discovered in the future, that's the API that would be mitigated.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This does give me the memory location like the code in my original question. But is the hashValue of that memory location a security threat in the case I provided?

Comment: Thanks, this answers the entire question.