# Swift vane attempt to print variable address -> Simulateneous accesses to 0xXXX, but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
        let name = file.name
        withUnsafePointer(to: &file) {
            print ("GETDEPOSIT: \(name) \(file.nameSuffix)   file has address: \($0)")
        }
```

[image: I really, really, really hate swift, its runtime and its "integration" with xcode]

I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me where there is modification and why
this new piece of shit technology requires such a weird dance just to print a variable address. I already spent an hour trying to figure this out.

```
class BVFile { ... }
class OperationCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var file: BVFile!
}
```

UPD Thanks Martin R and Sweeper. Sweeper's answer fixes the crash indeed
but the addresses do differ:

```
GETDEPOSIT: Сберегательный вкл@д 166,63 BYN Optional(" 166,63 BYN")   file has address: 0x00007fd8fc555578 0x0000600003194840
GETDEPOSIT: Зручны анл@йн 0 BYN Optional(" 0 BYN")   file has address: 0x00007fd8fc55e138 0x00006000031ea040
```

that was produced by this

```
        let address = Unmanaged.passUnretained(file).toOpaque()
        withUnsafePointer(to: &file) {
            print ("GETDEPOSIT: \(name) \($0.pointee?.nameSuffix)   file has address: \($0) \(address)")
        }
```

Comment: file is a force unwrapped var in OperationCell. amended the question

Comment: got address like this let address = Unmanaged.passUnretained(file).toOpaque() but still am curious why old swift way failed

Comment: What happens if you remove the address-of operator? `withUnsafePointer(to: file) {...}`

Comment: @MartinR That makes it a different address, doesn't it?

Comment: @MartinR [With and without the `&` does seem to produce different addresses.](https://repl.it/repls/CarefulDotingDemoware#main.swift)  Don't know which one the OP needs...

Comment: @Sweeper: You are right. And none of them is equal to the value of `Unmanaged.passUnretained(file).toOpaque()`

Comment: Indeed, the addresses mismatch Unmanaged.passUnretained(file).toOpaque() with or without "&". The wonderful world of swift.

Comment: From what I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777692/5133585), `&file` gives you the address of where the reference is stored. `toOpaque` gives you where the object's data (i.e. name and name suffix) is stored. As for without the `&`... I don't know...

Comment: There should be a link to this discussion from the tesarus entry describing "a path to hell is paved with good intentions". Apparently the language should be better with a hell to pay for direct pointer access, but essentially you get a random number generator instead of a useful address of a class instance :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2431879-withunsafepointer) says it pretty clearly:

> `value`:

> An instance to temporarily use via pointer. Note that the inout exclusivity rules mean that, like any other inout argument, **`value` cannot be directly accessed by other code for the duration of body.** Access must only occur through the pointer argument to `body` until `body` returns.

So you can't access `file` directly in the `{ ... }`. What you can do, is use `$0.pointee`:

```
print ("GETDEPOSIT: \(name) \($0.pointee.nameSuffix) file has address: \($0)")
```