# Get GCD label in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, xcode8

I've got some code that gets the label of the current GCD queue for logging purposes that looks like this in Swift 2:

```
if let queueName
    = String(UTF8String: dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL)) where !queueName.isEmpty {
    detailedMessage += "[" + queueName + "] "
}
```

After Xcode 8 converted this to Swift 3, it looks like this:

```
if let queueName
    = String(validatingUTF8: DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL.label), !queueName.IsEmpty {
    detailedMessage += "[" + queueName + "] "
}
```

However Xcode gives me the following error when I build:

> Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'label'

I haven't found any way to get the current queue label in Swift 3.  Can someone help?

Thanks,
***David***

**UPDATED**
Here's the function for context:

```
public func log(_ message: String,
                tag: String,
                level: Logger.LogLevel,
                userInfo: [String : String]?,
                functionName: StaticString,
                fileName: StaticString,
                lineNumber: Int) {

    var detailedMessage = ""

    let formattedDate = self._dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    detailedMessage += "\(formattedDate) "

    detailedMessage += "[\(level.description)] "

    if Thread.isMainThread {
        detailedMessage += "[main] "
    } else {
        if let threadName = Thread.current.name , !threadName.isEmpty {
            detailedMessage += "[" + threadName + "] "
        } else if let queueName
            = String(validatingUTF8: DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL.label) , !queueName.isEmpty {
            detailedMessage += "[" + queueName + "] "
        } else {
            detailedMessage += "[" + String(format:"%p", Thread.current) + "] "
        }
    }

    let lastPathComponent = NSString(stringLiteral: fileName).lastPathComponent
    detailedMessage += "[" + lastPathComponent + ":" + String(lineNumber) + "] "

    detailedMessage += "\(functionName) "

    let fullMessage = self.messageWithTag(tag, message: message)
    detailedMessage += "> \(fullMessage)"

    NSLog("\(fullMessage)")
}
```

Comment: Given that `DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL` is `NULL`, it appears you can do `String(validatingUTF8: __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil))`. But that gives me the willies.

Comment: @Rob Thanks.  That works, but I agree with you.  If that turns out to be a private API, then we'll probably be unhappy when we try to submit our app.

Comment: Since `dispatch_queue_get_label` and `DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL` are both documented, this is probably just an oversight on Apple's part. You should file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that method

```
let cName = __dispatch_queue_get_label(nil)
let name = String(cString: cName, encoding: .utf8)
```